# Understanding everything is set in axiomatic set theory

Tags: set-theory

When I  read *a book of set theory* written by Charles Pinter, in chapter 1 section 7, the author says

> If $A$ is any set, there is an element $a\in A$ such that $a\cap A=\emptyset$.

The author calls it the axiom of foundation. Let $A=\{red,blue\}$, by this axiom, we know $red \cap A=\emptyset$, but in native set theory $red \cap A$ makes no sense, I know in axiomatic set theory everything is set, but how to explain this contradiction? Are set in naive set theory and set in axiomatic set theory the same?

Comment: Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity#Regularity_in_the_presence_of_urelements answer your question?

Comment: why $red\cap A$ makes no sense?

Comment: @zaphodxvii - because $\text {red}$ is a *color*.

Comment: How do you explain "everything is binary data" in computers? Surely this comment is not binary data per se. So... How do you cope with that?

Comment: It doesn't matter what $red$ is... What matters is what $x\cap y=z$ means, since $\cap$ is not a fundamental symbol in the Language Of Set Theory,  but a "defined notion". In other words, $x\cap y=z$ is an abbreviation for a "formula" in LOST. What is that formula?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several tensions between naive and axiomatic set theory. The big one, of course, is "naive" versus "axiomatic" - are we looking at an *informal* or *formal* theory? This question, though, focuses on a different tension: the tension between being *maximally inclusive* and being *meaningfully specific*.

In short, the situation is this:

> Not every "naive set" is a set in the sense of axiomatic set theory.

---

Here's a bit more detail:

Things like "red" and "blue" simply *don't exist* from the point of view of axiomatic set theory *(at least, [the usual version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory); not every form of axiomatic set theory includes the axiom of foundation, or even asserts that all objects are sets!)*. If you wish, you can think of standard axiomatic set theory as describing *a portion of* the mathematical universe - namely, the part which can be "built out of $\emptyset$" just by the basic set operations (including powerset and transfinite recursion - so, maybe "basic" is misleading!).

Put another way, it's obvious that any theory of sets needs to be able to talk about $\emptyset$. Well, $\{\emptyset\}$ is also a set, so that should be included. By contrast, if all we want to do is talk about sets, there's no obvious reason why something like "red" should be in our universe. Axiomatic set theory studies the concept of set *on its own* in a sense. In light of this, it should be surprising that something actually interesting (let alone powerful enough to implement all of mathematics) comes out!

Comment: thank you, I still have a question, in wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity#Regularity_in_the_presence_of_urelements    
it assumes A is not an empty set, but in Pinter's book, it has no such assumption, is it assumption necessary?

Comment: @noname1014: Yes, the assumption that $A$ is nonempty is definitely necessary in the Axiom of Foundation. It is clearly not true for $A=\varnothing$. If your author has forgotten it, that's an error in the book.

Answer (score 0):

He is probably saying that $a$ is also a set. For example $$A=\{0,\{1\}\}$$let $a=\{1\}\in A$ therefore $$a\cap A=\phi$$

Comment: That's really not the question here.